# Can a image be render on planes through scripting?

Tags: python, materials, external-applications

Setup: Blender 2.82

I have multiple images that i take from a CNN and i want to put on planes

I tried like this:

```
mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name='test')
mat.use_nodes = True
bsdf = mat.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"]
texImage = mat.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
texImage.image = bpy.data.images.load(image)
mat.node_tree.links.new(bsdf.inputs['Base Color'], texImage.outputs['Color'])

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(location=(k, y,  l ))
bpy.context.active_object.name = 'plane'
plane = bpy.context.object

if plane.data.materials:
     plane.data.materials[0] = mat
else:
     plane.data.materials.append(mat)
```

How can the image be loaded from an numpy array of pixels ?

Additionally to this, does the image added to the plane needs to respect some format?

Comment: That's because it's called [ShaderNodeTexImage](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ShaderNodeTexImage.html).

Comment: Thanks for noticing, i updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution is to save the image that you want to put it on the plane and to load the image from there:

```
texImage.image = bpy.data.images.load("path to your image saved previously in code")
```