# Can a realtime webcam image be displayed on a plane through scripting?

Tags: python, scripting, materials, motion-capture

Setup: Blender 2.82

I want to display my webcam in real-time on a plane.

I managed to render images from my computer on a plane here.[Can a image be render on planes through scripting?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173781/can-a-image-be-render-on-planes-through-scripting)

However i did not manage to find something useful to try to capture in real-time my webcam continuously via a python script. So to open the camera and to display the image on the plane

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blender is more geared towards content creation and is not the right software for your project.

You can write a python operator which continuously grabs frame from the webcam and writes them onto an image texture.

1. Add an **image texture** and name it `image`.
2. Add a **3D object** and texture it with the image. You will have to go to material or rendered view to see the image.
3. Create a new **text block**. Write a modal timer operator. You can get the structure for this script in the text editor menu: *Templates > Python > Operator Modal Timer*.
   The *modal timer operator* is a Blender operator, which can be called from the interface and starts a timer. The timer calls a function at a fixed interval. In this function, we'll grab the camera frame and write it on to the image.
4. **Install *opencv-python***, which can access the webcam. Identify the folder which contains the python executable Blender is using. You can do this by going into the python console and typing `import sys` and in a new line `sys.exec_prefix`. Upon pressing enter you will see the path to the python executable folder. Go to that path (`...\2.82\python\bin`) and open a new command line interface. Install `opencv-python` with the command `python -m pip install opencv-python`, which will also install other relevant modules like `numpy`. Restart Blender.

Now that you're setup, open the modal operator and remove all content from it's classes methods. When entering the modal operator, `execute` is called. In this method, we have to initialize the modal *timer*, the opencv *VideoCapture* and a reference to the *image* in Blender.

```
def execute(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.5, window=context.window)
        self._cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self._img = bpy.data.images['image']
        self._size = tuple(self._img.size)
        
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
```

The `modal` method is called every timer tick. As in the template, let's leave the check for an exit condition (like a pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd> key) when we exit the modal operator. On a timer tick, we start by grabbing the frame with the opencv VideoCapture object.

```
ret, frame = self._cap.read()
```

Then we resize the captured frame to fit our blender images dimensions.

```
resized = cv2.resize(frame, self._size, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

To make the numpy array (which is the image opencv produced form the webcam) compatible with Blender's image datablock, we'll have to flip the R and B channels as well as the Y-dimension, convert the image pixels to floats and flatten it. (Blender expects image data to be a long list of rgba pixel values.)
This resulting "list" can be assigned to the `pixels` property of a Blender image.

```
rgb = np.flip(resized, axis=[0, 2])
rgba = np.ones((self._size[1], self._size[0], 4), dtype=np.float32)
rgba[:,:,:-1] = np.float32(rgb) / 255
self._img.pixels = rgba.flatten()
```

The full script at the end of this answer. Run it by pressing *Run Script* in the text editor. This will add the modal operator to Blenders runtime memory. In the 3D view, press F3 and type the name of your modal operator (the `bl_label` of your class). I named the classes `bl_label` `Modal Timer Operator` as in the template. Then click on the result.

*Run this script at your own risk. Blender might crash, remember to backup.*

While the framerate is insanely low, I can see my camera capture writing to the image. However the viewport updates sampling method doesn't get enough samples to udpate the image enough.

[image: webcam capture]

While my answer gives a method to inject your webcam image into Blender in "realtime", it clearly lacks speed and almost removes the Interactivity from the user interface. To make this remotely usable, you would have to implement multithreading storing the images in some sort of concurrent bag.

```
import bpy
import cv2
import numpy as np

class ModalTimerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_timer_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal Timer Operator"

    _timer = None
    _cap = None
    _img = None
    _size = None

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {'ESC'}:
            self.cancel(context)
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        if event.type == 'TIMER':
            ret, frame = self._cap.read()
            resized = cv2.resize(frame, self._size, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
            rgb = np.flip(resized, axis=[0, 2])

            rgba = np.ones((self._size[1], self._size[0], 4), dtype=np.float32)
            rgba[:,:,:-1] = np.float32(rgb) / 255
            self._img.pixels = rgba.flatten()
            
        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.5, window=context.window)
        self._cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self._img = bpy.data.images['image']
        self._size = tuple(self._img.size)
        
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)
        self._cap.release()


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalTimerOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalTimerOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

To access this through the search, we need to append it to `VIEW3D_MT_view`. (See [Basic Operator Example](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html#basic-operator-example).)

```
def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(ModalTimerOperator.bl_idname, text="Modal Opencv Capture Timer")

bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_view.append(menu_func)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked perfectly.

Comment: Hi Leande sorry to reach you thru here, I couldn't find any email related in your profile here. Can we talk? andrepazleal@gmail.com

Comment: @andre Use @ Leander to ping me in [this room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111705/re-can-a-realtime-webcam-image-be-displayed-on-a-plane-through-scripting).

Comment: hi i tried this script but its not working. im really interested in getting this work i run the script and then press f3 and try to search for the modal object but it doesn't show up.

Comment: @Dan See edited last paragraph. The `VIEW3D_MT_view.append` function should be called at the end of `register`.